# Unable to find an entry point named of function in DLL?

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

In the C++ DLL:

```
struct APP_PARAM
{
    int numData;
    LPCSTR *text;
    int *values;
};

int App::StartApp(APP_PARAM params)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        OutputDebugString(params.text[i]);
    }
}
```

In VB.NET :

```
<StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Public Structure APP_PARAM
    Public numData As Integer
    Public text As System.IntPtr
    Public values As System.IntPtr
  End Structure

  Declare Function StartApp Lib "AppSupport.dll" (ByVal params As APP_PARAM) As Integer

  Sub Main()

    Dim params As APP_PARAM
    params.numData = 3

    Dim text As String() = {"A", "B", "C"}
    Dim textHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(text)
    params.text = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(textHandle)

    Dim values As Integer() = {10, 20, 30}
    Dim valuesHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(values)
    params.values = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(heightHandle)

    StartApp(params)

    textHandle.Free()
    valuesHandle.Free()

  End Sub
```

When I Implement this I got error find entry point of DLL. I want to use structure of C++ into VB, What possible solutions can be used to avoid this?

Comment: You are making multiple mistakes, GCHandle.ToIntPtr() does not do what you hope it does.  You guessed at the exported name of the function wrong, its name will be "mangled" by the C++ compiler.  Something you can see with the Dumpbin.exe /exports utility.  And you cannot pinvoke this function, calling instance methods of a C++ class requires writing a wrapper in the C++/CLI language.  You can only pinvoke a *static* function.

Comment: I don't Understand. What you are trying to say?

Comment: You cannot make this work.  Clear now?

Comment: ok. I will find another way.